# Multiple LAS files- Define Projection

Tags: python, coordinate-system, las

I am looking for some help drafting code to define the coordinate system for multiple las files. I have seen plenty on how to batch define projections with rasters and shapefiles, but nothing on las files. Is there a lis command for las data? Could that be used in a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

LAS files can have information regarding coordinate reference system (CRS) defined in header. Lots of .las files do not have information about CRS stored. You can use different tools to get this data.

- [lasstools (lasinfo)](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/) - you can create batch script to see what is in header and which CRS is set.

  lasinfo -i lidar.laz -odix _info -otxt
- [laspy](https://pypi.org/project/laspy/#description) - probably you can use it to get header data out of each file, have not tested it.